# Bug in PF&M Icon

Tags: bug

It might just be me, but there seems to be a bug in which icon is shown in the list of SE sites:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

No problem here. Try another browser. Then flush the cache. Then try a third one.

On a lighter note -

[image]

On meta, the system considers you a new contributor, and reminded me to be nice. I hope I was sufficiently pleasant.

Comment: Hmm. Problem seems to have gone away. Probably user error. Thanks for checking, Joe!

Comment: @DStanley I can't see how it could be user error, but it won't be worth investigating unless you could reproduce it consistently.

Comment: Welcome to meta and thanks for being nice to newbie :)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - re: your last sentence - your pleasentness was sufficient :)

Comment: When in doubt, blame caching.